# Where can I find a "bee melon"?

Tags: identification, fruits

My wife remembers a shrub(?) that grew in the Azores that was called a bee melon or Melão de abelha.

She describes it as growing from a bush that produced small white flowers, and then a pale whitish fruit that tasted sweet and floral.

Does anyone know anything about this plant?

Comment: How big were the fruits? Melon or cantaloupe sized? What colour was the flesh of the fruit (I'm assuming your description of 'pale whitish' applies to the skin)

Comment: They were described to me as being about the size of a blueberry. The flesh might have been a similar pale color, but she's not sure.

Comment: A Google image search for ["Melão de abelha Azores"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mel%C3%A3o+de+abelha+Azores&tbm=isch) shows [Passionflower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora_edulis) (or a close relative) as the first couple of hits. I wonder if it could be a local name for it.

Comment: @Niall C Passiflora fruits are much bigger than blueberries though, slightly larger than a kiwi fruit, say, though they are the right colour.

Comment: Hi! Is this the plant you're looking for? [Trigona spinipes](http://www.flickr.com/photos/valedaneblina/9456048823/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what it might have been, but would hazard a guess at some kind of Vaccinium - this is the group that includes blueberries, but there are white flowered and berried forms, though I've never actually come across one.